How to force gt to keep column format in summary rows?
I have table to present with different types of measurements in each column.
Different columns need different formating (decimal numbers).
I can do it before I construct GT table or in GT table using fmt_number().
I need to sumarise this table by column (N, mean, median, max, min, sd and cv).
grand_summary_rows works great here.
Except there is a problem. Functions used in summaries produce results with 6 decimals.
I want most summary parameters (except N and CV) to have the same number of decimals as summarised column.
I've tried to put grand_summary_rows before fmt_number (with rows = everything()) lines in hope that it will format summary rows in the same way as data. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.
I know that I can use formatting inside grand_summary_rows like I did for N and CV and specify format again like I did for data columns
fmt = list(~ fmt_number(., columns = matches("tmax"), decimals = 2) #like this line
          ~ fmt_number(., rows = "n", decimals = 0),
          ~ fmt_percent(., rows = "cv", decimals = 2))

I feel like there should be better option than doubling formatting for each column once fore data second time for statistics.
Is there any workaround that I missed to do it once for whole table? Some parameter to specify that makes fmt_ functions work really on every row?

Based on the bit of information you provided, I'm not sure what you mean by a better way....short of gt reading your mind? Perhaps I don't fully understand what you're asking. If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from dput() or reprex::reprex(). Check it out: making R reproducible questions.
